# Node / React app, packaging for Linux with pkg

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to package a node / react app as a native executable for each of Mac / Windows / Linux, using the node package 'pkg' (https://github.com/zeit/pkg/).

I can run the application with node on my machine without issue. I was also successfully able to use pkg to build and run the Mac version, and it works as expected. With the Linux version, the pkg build works (ie no errors), but I am getting an error when running the executable.

`Error spawn /snapshot/IXmapsClient/node_modules/open/xdg-open ENOENT`
(more detailed version below)

My understanding is that snapshot is the 'internal' directory created by pkg. The node module dir and file exists at ~/Dev/IXmaps/IXmapsClient/node_modules/open/ and has the correct permissions (along with all other required node_modules used by this application).

**Details of what I'm working with:**

- Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm working on a Virtualbox VM with OSX underneath, in the event that that is relevant)
- Node 10
- Pkg 4.4.2 (pkg -t node10-linux-x64 server.js -o dist/linux/IXmapsClient --config package.json)

**Full error message:**

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /snapshot/IXmapsClient/node_modules/open/xdg-open ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1317:13)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:320:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:659:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:659:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else encounters this issue, it looks to have been resolved. The author of the 'pkg' module has added support for the 'open' module with this commit: https://github.com/zeit/pkg/commit/db8487acd2d40af7b0cb1e63e133a707f93d725f